# Method of Moment

Tags: parameter-estimation

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTbZP0yt9qc) lecture on method of moment, we have:

[image]
[image]

[image]
why is gradient of psi inverse a dxd matrix?
K-th moment $m_k$is defined as $ \mathbb E[X^k] $ and can be estimated by the average using Law of Large Numbers which here is represented by $\hat m_k$
My understanding is that the inverse function $\psi^-1 $  takes the vector of moments of size d, so why isn't the gradient of size d?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Your question is cryptic. You should explain what the moments (with an "s" are, with repect to which they are taken etc.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh what a life saver thanks for the tip. I incorporated it.

Comment: @JeanMarie I added the definition of moments in statistics. Is that now more clear? Thank you so much for providing feedback on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Normally, for a function $\psi$ that goes from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R$ then you have to take the derivative of the function in regards to each of the d parameters and you will have a vector of size d. In this case $\psi$ is a function from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R^d$ therefore you will end up with a d-dimensional array for each of d elements in the "y" side.